# Joining Based on the Max Date <= a Given Date

Tags: sql, netezza, aginity

I've got two tables that look something like this:

Table 1:

```
Unit      Date
A         9/30/17
B         9/30/17
```

Table 2:

```
Unit     Date      Metric
A        9/30/17   100
A        6/30/17   250
A        5/31/17   150
B        8/15/17   200
B        4/30/17   150
B        4/15/17   100
```

For each combination of Unit and Date from Table 1, I want to pull back the corresponding Metric value from Table 2.  If there is not a match in Table 2, I want to pull back the Metric value for the next closest date that is < the date from Table 1.  Using the examples above, I would expect to get 100 for Unit A and 200 for Unit B.

How can I get this into query form?  I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around it.  It would be easy if I was just dealing with dates, but the Unit component is what's throwing me off.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We are on Netezza 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact match is relatively easy by using a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.Unit, t2.Metric
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Unit = t1.Unit AND t2.Date = t1.Date
```

With this query t2.Metric will be NULL if there is no exact match.
To get the metric without an exact match is trickier. In MS SQL Server you could write a user defined function (UDF) to return the closest value.

```
create function dbo.udfGetMetric(@Unit char(1), @Date datetime) returns int
as 
BEGIN
declare @Metric smallint;
SELECT TOP(1) @Metric = Metric
FROM Table2 
WHERE Unit = @Unit
    and [Date] < @Date
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;

RETURN @Metric;
END
GO
```

You can then call this function in your query when the value is NULL

```
SELECT t1.Unit, ISNULL(t2.Metric, dbo.udfGetMetric(t1.Unit, t1.[Date])) as Metric
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Unit = t1.Unit AND t2.[Date] = t1.[Date];
```

You can do the same by using a subquery instead of a function:

```
SELECT t1.Unit
, ISNULL(t2.Metric, (SELECT TOP(1) Metric
                    FROM Table2 
                    WHERE Unit = t1.Unit
                        and [Date] < t1.[Date]
                    ORDER BY [Date] DESC)) as Metric
FROM Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Unit = t1.Unit AND t2.[Date] = t1.[Date];
```